# Installing the Google Chrome Flash debugger on Windows

Tags: google-chrome, flash

I'm trying to debug an issue in Flash Player that I have managed to fix in Firefox and Internet Explorer, Chrome however refuses to cooperate.

So I'm stuck with tracking down this Chrome specific issue. But as far as I can tell there's no way to get the Flash Debugger working on Chrome for Windows. I've read a few 'solutions' to this problem but most of these were for Mac or were for older versions of Chrome.

I tried disabling the Adobe Flash Player plugin in Chrome's `chrome://plugins/` page and installing the `Flash Player content debugger for Opera and Chromium based applications – PPAPI` plugin, it doesn't seem to install successfully however as it doesn't show up in the plugins list nor am I able to view Flash Player content.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue, however I was able to have the NPAPI debugger installed for a while. I think the key is the version of player. I found that it is impossible to install the adobe debugger if its version number is lower than the version of chrome flash player. I had the debugger working for about 2 months, but now I'm unable to install it since its version is 21.0.0.197 while chrome has just updated its player to version 21.0.0.213. Also I have found that sometimes I need to run non-personalized version of chrome right after installation. All I can do now is to wait for new version of adobe debugger.

[Edit]
I've found deleting folder with its plugin (the one with version in the name) can help temporary ;) After browser restart I saw debugger in plugins instead.